# I can't receive POST data into application on AWS nginx server PHP

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, rest, nginx

I've got this very odd problem...on my remote web server for this specific application, when I try to receive JSON input (in any way) I either get a NULL or empty ("") return. The odd part about this problem, is that it is working fine on my local machine. And when I say "working fine" what that means is that I can make a request via Postman to my local machine's API endpoint and it does what it's supposed to do. The other odd thing is that on this very web server (in different files, but still this web server), I can receive JSON input just fine.

I have tried different ways of sending the JSON data to this remote server as well. I have raw cURLed the data, I have sent it from Postman, I have sent it from the webhooks app in Zapier, and I have sent it from a different application's webhook functionality. All of these different applications have given me a NULL return on trying to retreive the JSON data. Here's how I'm trying to retrieve it:

```
// index.php, the API endpoint processing file
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../../model/model.php';

use ShinePHP\{Crud, CrudException, EasyHttp, EasyHttpException, HandleData, HandleDataException};

try {
    $data = EasyHttp::turnJsonInputIntoArray();
} catch (EasyHttpException $ehe) {
    echo json_encode(['status' => 'failure', 'message' => $ehe->getMessage()]);
    exit;
}
```

And this is the `turnJsonInputIntoArray()` method in the EasyHttp class:

```
public static function turnJsonInputIntoArray(string $urlToRetrieveFrom = 'php://input') : array {

    // Check if JSON is null, if it is, throw EasyHttpException, if not, return the decoded assoc array.
    if (json_decode(file_get_contents($urlToRetrieveFrom), true) === null) {
        throw new EasyHttpException('No data retrieved from url: '.$urlToRetrieveFrom);
    } else {
        return json_decode(file_get_contents($urlToRetrieveFrom), true);
    }

}
```

I've var_dumped `$_POST` (it returned an empty array), `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` (returned NULL), and `file_get_contents('php://input')` (returned an empty string). Nothing exists in the nginx error log aside from the custom exception that exists because there is nothing in php://input. Nothing has worked and I really don't know how else to receive my JSON data.

**How can I receive JSON data into my PHP script running on a remote server?**

Comment: Is your local machine also a nginx server?

Comment: @Pipe no, its Apache. But, on this exact same server, I have other web API endpoints running using this method of receiving JSON data, and it's working

Comment: Then, why not using Apache on AWS?

Comment: @Smankusors because I believe nginx is a superior web server for what we're trying to do. I'm in the process of transitioning everything on my machine to nginx, I'm just still using XAMPP for small little projects like this one

Comment: Try `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`. Is the output expected?

Comment: @Smankusors no, the output is an empty string

Comment: How about... Error logs?

Comment: @Smankusors good point, I'll add that to the question. There is nothing in the nginx error log, the only error being thrown is the exception I'm catching because there is nothing in php://input